# How to access managedObjectContext in my own background queue after iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, concurrency

I realized that the in core data, when you init an `NSManagedObjectContext`, `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` is deprecated after iOS 9.0. I would like to access `NSManagedObjectContext` in my own background queue with concurrency = 1. I know that the Moc of `privateQueueConcurrencyType` will create its own queue to execute code and merge to a parent Moc, which seems not what I want. (`mainQueueConcurrencyType` will run the code on main queue which is not what I want either)

Is there anyway that I can manage core data to run in my own background queue?

Answer (score 1):

`NSConfinementConcurrencyType` is deprecated.  That means you should not use it.

You have two choices.

1. Access a MOC of `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` on the main queue.
2. Access a MOC of either `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` or `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` from any thread you want, but using the `performBlock` and `performBlockAndWait` API.

I strongly suggest using the `performBlock` API.

Also, using a MOC of `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` does not require using a parent/child relationship.